# scikit-learn PCA: matrix transformation produces PC estimates with flipped signs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm using scikit-learn to perform PCA on [this dataset](https://gist.github.com/ccheaton/8393329). The scikit-learn documentation [states that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA)

> Due to implementation subtleties of the Singular Value Decomposition
>   (SVD), which is used in this implementation, running fit twice on the
>   same matrix can lead to principal components with signs flipped
>   (change in direction). For this reason, it is important to always use
>   the same estimator object to transform data in a consistent fashion.

The problem is that I don't think that I'm using different estimator objects, but the signs of some of my PCs are flipped, when compared to results in SAS's `PROC PRINCOMP` procedure.

For the first observation in the dataset, the SAS PCs are:

```
PC1      PC2      PC3       PC4      PC5
2.0508   1.9600   -0.1663   0.2965   -0.0121
```

From scikit-learn, I get the following (which are very close in magnitude):

```
PC1      PC2      PC3       PC4      PC5
-2.0536  -1.9627  -0.1666   -0.297   -0.0122
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from sklearn.decomposition.pca import PCA

sourcef = pd.read_csv('C:/mydata.csv')
frame = pd.DataFrame(sourcef)

# Some pandas evals, regressions, etc... that I'm not showing
# but not affecting the matrix

# Make sure we are working with the proper data -- drop the response variable
cols = [col for col in frame.columns if col not in ['response']]

# Separate out the data matrix from the response variable vector 
# into numpy arrays
frame2_X = frame[cols].values
frame2_y = frame['response'].values

# Standardize the values
X_means = np.mean(frame2_X,axis=0)
X_stds  = np.std(frame2_X,axis=0)

y_mean = np.mean(frame2_y)
y_std  = np.std(frame2_y)

frame2_X_stdz = np.copy(frame2_X)
frame2_y_stdz = frame2_y.astype(numpy.float32, copy=True)

for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(frame2_X_stdz):
    frame2_X_stdz[x][y] = (value - X_means[y])/X_stds[y]

for index, value in enumerate(frame2_y_stdz):
    frame2_y_stdz[index] = (float(value) - y_mean)/y_std

# Show the first 5 elements of the standardized values, to verify
print frame2_X_stdz[:,0][:5]

# Show the first 5 lines from the standardized response vector, to verify
print frame2_y_stdz[:5]
```

Those check out ok:

```
[ 0.9508 -0.5847 -0.2797 -0.4039 -0.598 ]
[ 1.0726 -0.5009 -0.0942 -0.1187 -0.8043]
```

Continuing on...

```
# Create a PCA object
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(frame2_X_stdz)

# Create the matrix of PC estimates
pca.transform(frame2_X_stdz)
```

Here's the output of the last step:

```
Out[16]: array([[-2.0536, -1.9627, -0.1666, -0.297 , -0.0122],
       [ 1.382 , -0.382 , -0.5692, -0.0257, -0.0509],
       [ 0.4342,  0.611 ,  0.2701,  0.062 , -0.011 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.0422,  0.7251, -0.1926,  0.0089,  0.0005],
       [ 1.4502, -0.7115, -0.0733,  0.0013, -0.0557],
       [ 0.258 ,  0.3684,  0.1873,  0.0403,  0.0042]])
```

I've tried it by replacing the `pca.fit()` and `pca.transform()` with `pca.fit_transform()`, but I end up with the same results.

What am I doing wrong here that I'm getting PCs with the signs flipped?

Comment: This might be better answered on: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The reason I posted it here instead of there is because it seems more specific to the scikit-learn implementation (and how I'm using it) than the statistics.

Comment: IMHO it's math, not stats. In fact, there is no sign in SVD (additive inverse of an eigenvector is an eigenvector), they are there via implementation, not by definition. Hence, sign of PC is also undefined.

Comment: @alko That being the case, how do you reconcile results between SAS and Python when performing PC regression? The parameter estimates on the regression coefficients also are different in sign. I understand this doesn't matter much if you're just doing variable reduction.

Answer (score 8):

You're doing nothing wrong.

What the documentation is warning you about is that repeated calls to `fit` may yield different principal components - not how they relate to another PCA implementation.

Having a flipped sign on all components doesn't make the result **wrong** - the result is right as long as it fulfills the definition (each component is chosen such that it captures the maximum amount of variance in the data). As it stands, it seems the projection you got is simply mirrored - it still fulfills the definition, and is, thus, correct.

If, beneath correctness, you're worried about consistency between implementations, you can simply multiply the components by -1, when it's necessary.

Comment: They don't seem to be consistently flipped. PCs 1, 2, and 4 are flipped, but not 3 and 5. I'm not really worried about consistency, per se. I was just trying to duplicate some SAS homework in Python and was concerned about the different signs. The next step in the HW is to perform a principal component regression (b/c the dataset has significant multicollinearity) and I'm worried the flipped signs will lead to different results.

Comment: @Clay I'm by no means a expert in statistics, but it seems to me that since  (on a principal component regression) the regression coefficients are transformed **back** into the original space using the PC eigenvectors, the results should be the same, as long as you use the same transformation for PCA and regression

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll continue and compare the PCR results.

Comment: The PCR results have flipped signs on the parameter estimates. Not sure how to reconcile that with SAS output.

Answer (score 3):

SVD decompositions are not guaranteed unique - only the values will be identical, as different implementations of svd() can produce different signs. Any of the eigenvectors can have flipped signs, and will produce identical results when transformed, then transformed back into the original space. Most algorithms in sklearn which use SVD decomposition use the function sklearn.utils.extmath.svd_flip() to correct this, and enforce an identical convention across algorithms. For historical reasons, PCA() never got this fix (though maybe it should...)

In general, this is not something to worry about - just a limitation of the SVD algorithm as typically implemented.

On an additional note, I find assigning importance to PC weights (and parameter weights in general) dangerous, because of exactly these kinds of issues. Numerical/implementation details should not influence your analysis results, but many times it is hard to tell what is a result of the data, and what is a result of the algorithms you use for exploration. I know this is a homework assignment, not a choice, but it is important to keep these things in mind!